# Link to a specific slide in carousel with Javascript/CSS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, slideshow, hashtag

There have been other questions similar to this, but the answers always pertain to specific JQuery code that I'm not using. Instead, I'm using the W3Schools Slideshow example here:

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

I have links on a different page, and I'd like each of those links to open the slideshow page on a specific slide.

The most recent thing I tried is this:

LINK on separate page:

```
<a href="slideshow.html#currentSlide(3)">
```

Dot links under the slideshow on slideshow.html (couldn't think of anything else to link to):

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
   <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span>
</div>
```

And javascript that supposedly tells the slideshow what to load based on the hash:

```
if (location.hash)
{
    $('#' + location.hash.substring(1)).click();
}
```

Probably a dumb idea, but I'm relatively new to this stuff and am out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it, but you've got one issue. Your script that handles which item to show references an element that doesn't exist. You wrote:

```
$('#' + location.hash.substring(1)).click();
```

Which is going to evaluate to something like this:

```
$('#currentSlide(1)').click();
```

That tells jQuery to target an element with `id=currentSlide(1)`, which doesn't exist on your page.

What I would recommend instead is to name your URL fragments with just the index of the image you want to show, like this:

```
<a href="slideshow.html#0">Image 1</a>
<a href="slideshow.html#1">Image 2</a>
<a href="slideshow.html#2">Image 3</a>
```

Then in the `slideshow.html` page use this command to trigger the click event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (location.hash) {
    var hash = location.hash.slice(1);
    $(".dot").eq(hash).click();
  }
});
```

That will look for the `dot` class [at the index provided](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), and click that element.

Comment: When I did this, it just displayed all the slides together on the page in a vertical formation, one on top of the other all the way down the page.. It's possible I did something wrong!

Comment: I think that you're missing to wrap your code inside the document loaded event. 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    // your js here
}, false);

Comment: I didn't do anything to change what's displayed, all I did was change your JavaScript. Can you clarify the exact issue you're having now? Are you getting any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
if(location.hash){
     //assuming you have a hash like this -> slide1
     var slide =  location.hash;
     var slideNumber = slide.replace("#slide","");
     currentSlide(slide);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it takes me to the slideshow page without any slides. It's just the dots without any picture above them.